# Nvidia Grub max boot resolution 1280x1024 (15.10)

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, display-resolution

After installing Nvidia drivers (I assume its that, fresh install looked fine) I can no longer boot grub with 1920x1080.

I have tried the normal solutions with adding:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

I´ve entered "c" in grub boot and this is the highest resolution i see there.
The splash also looks bad (like an 8bit nintendo) when loading Ubuntu.

Is there any way to solve this other than reverting to X driver?
(would reverting cause performance issues? i dont play in linux, mostly video managing and editing / mediaserver / other servers...)

Comment: There is no way with a proprietary driver. Why do you need grub with high resolution?

Comment: I dont, its just annoying....

Comment: Try adding GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080` on the off chance it works, but have a LiveCD/LiveUSB handy just in case grub dies.

Comment: I´ve done that and it just reverts to 640 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the proprietary driver does not support high resolution during boot-up.  You could uninstall the proprietary drivers, but graphics performance will not be near as good.  You can remove the proprietary drivers for the Software and Updates dialog (though I would not recommend it).

Comment: What kind of performance drop are we talking about? Like i mentioned, I use it as a workstation / Server.

Comment: As a server, you could go with either driver, as the driver mainly affects the graphics performance.  As a workstation, it depends on the kind of work you do, and also on what desktop environment you use (Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Xubuntu (my personal favorite)/Lubuntu).

Comment: At first i hated Unity... I used one week trying to adapt cinnamon. When i  realized i could not get it the way i want i forced my self to try Unity, and now i love it. I did not think about Compiz and such...

So, sticking with proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone have experience with the [Ubuntu-X](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/x-updates) drivers? Would this fix the boot resolution?